# xgbTree in Caret predicting all values outside of model data range

Tags: r, regression, r-caret

I am trying to train a regression model with only 3 variables in Caret using `xgbTree`. The model predicts only 2 discrete values (2.3 and 2.6), both of which are outside the range of the model data (5 values between 2.8 and 4).

In addition, when I try to calculate the variable importance, I get the following warning message

> In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Only 1 variable is listed, with an importance of NaN.

Is anyone able to explain what I am doing wrong here? I have attached a simple example code to describe what I mean.

```
library("caret")
library("xgboost") 
library("plyr")

x_linear<- c(       
3.76, 3.88, 3.55, 3.47, 3.49, 3.44, 3.47, 3.49, 3.44, 3.92, 3.94, 3.55, 
3.61, 3.57, 3.46, 3.72, 3.96, 3.55, 3.34, 3.26, 3.46, 3.69, 3.69, 3.53,
3.85, 3.78, 3.55, 3.42, 3.36, 3.53, 3.98, 3.91, 3.55, 3.95, 3.82, 3.55,
3.07, 3.02, 3.44, 3.45, 3.24, 3.46, 3.83, 3.90, 3.55, 3.89, 3.96, 3.55,
3.84, 3.76, 3.55, 3.78, 3.94, 3.46, 3.28, 3.47, 3.44, 3.66, 3.66, 3.46,
3.81, 3.90, 3.46, 3.66, 3.64, 3.46, 3.70, 3.69, 3.53, 3.89, 3.85, 3.55,
3.89, 3.85, 3.55, 3.39, 3.50, 3.46, 3.59, 3.52, 3.55, 3.42, 3.29, 3.44,
3.28, 3.39, 3.46, 3.23, 3.17, 3.53, 3.57, 3.28, 3.46, 3.61, 3.60, 3.46,
3.08, 3.02, 3.44, 3.55, 3.63, 3.55, 3.60, 3.63, 3.55, 3.26, 3.27, 3.53,
3.26, 3.27, 3.53, 3.54, 3.62, 3.46, 3.54, 3.62, 3.55, 3.29, 3.30, 3.44,
3.60, 3.59, 3.55, 4.00, 3.98, 3.55, 3.25, 3.41, 3.55, 3.59, 3.66, 3.55,
3.47, 3.51, 3.46)
x <- matrix(x_linear, nrow = 45, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(x) <- c("x1","x2","x3")

y <- c(4.0, 3.7, 3.4, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.1, 3.4, 4.0, 3.4, 4.0, 4.0, 
2.8, 3.4, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.4, 3.7, 4.0, 3.7, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0,
3.4, 3.7, 3.4, 3.1, 3.1, 2.8, 3.4, 2.8, 3.7, 3.4, 3.1, 3.1, 4.0, 
3.7, 3.1, 3.7, 4.0, 2.8, 3.7, 3.7)

trainControl <- trainControl(summaryFunction=defaultSummary, 
   method="repeatedcv", repeats=3, number=8, selectionFunction="oneSE")
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.nrounds = 100, .max_depth = 6, .eta = 0.01,
   .gamma = 0, .colsample_bytree = 1, .min_child_weight= 10)

#split into training and test sets
set.seed(1)
nSamples <- length(y)
TrainingIndexes <- createDataPartition(y, p=0.8)[[1]]
TestIndexes <- (seq(1,nSamples))[-TrainingIndexes]

# Preprocess data
procValues <- preProcess(x[TrainingIndexes,], method=c("center", "scale"))
ProcedData <- predict(procValues, x)
ProcedTrainingData <- ProcedData[TrainingIndexes,]

set.seed(1)
fit.xgb <- train(x=ProcedTrainingData, y=y[TrainingIndexes], 
method="xgbTree",tuneGrid=tuneGrid,metric="RMSE", trControl=trainControl)
Imps <- varImp(fit.xgb)
Pred_y <- predict(fit.xgb, ProcedData)
plot(y[TrainingIndexes], Pred_y[TrainingIndexes],col="blue", 
xlab="Meas", ylab="Pred")
points(y[TestIndexes], Pred_y[TestIndexes],col="red")
```

Comment: When I run your code I get the error: `Error in train.default(x = ProcedTrainingData, y = y[TrainingIndexes],  : 
  The tuning parameter grid should have columns nrounds, max_depth, eta, gamma, colsample_bytree, min_child_weight, subsample` when creating fit.xgb

Comment: And when running it without creating `tuneGrid` and without calling `tuneGrid` in the `train` function It seems to give reasonable results with a range from 2.84 to 4.01

Comment: Hi Marijn, great, thanks for the input! I didn't get that error message - the version I am using doesn't require the subsample. But I guess that means that my Grid parameters are not good / have a problem. I had a look at the results using the default parameters and it seems like the '.min_child_weight' of 10 was the problem - setting it to 1 I get much better fits - maybe because the data set is so small? Thanks for your help!